# How To Access Server Side Variables On The Client Side Using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, server, client

I am trying to implement a feature that auto-generates a string/number starting from "5S-1" whenever a record is created. For example, if I go onto a web page and click "Create record," I want the number to auto-populate in the record ID field on the form to say "5S-1". When I try to create another record, it should start at "5S-2" now and increment from there whenever a record is created. I am using HTML, CSS, and Typescript as my programming languages. I'm also now trying to figure out how to access this variable "newId" that's on the server side on the client side because I need to display that on the form every time a user creates a new record. Here is some sample code on what I have in my server file.

```
Server Side:

/* new record */
router.post('/', async (request, response) => {
  let lastestId = "" + carQueries.id;
  let defVal = "0";
  let newId = '5S-' + defVal.substring(0, defVal.length - lastestId.length) + lastestId;
  try {

    newId = request.params.id;
    const results = await carQueries.getLastCarRecordById(newId)
    assert(results);
    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.json(results);
}  catch (error) {
    console.error('Exception in record POST');
    console.error(error);
    response.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

Comment: In order to fetch information from the server, the client would need to make a request to that server to get that information.  If the client is JavaScript on a web page then the technology you're looking for to do that is called "AJAX".

Comment: Or with a [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).

Comment: @David Is AJAX syntax similar to Javascript?

Comment: @markymark_prod: AJAX isn't a language.  It's basically a subset of operations performed in JavaScript.  So, yes, JavaScript syntax is very similar to JavaScript.

Comment: @David lol Ohhh, okay, sorry about that. I'm new to the web development world .

Comment: @David, I see that you said if I'm, I'm using JS on the front end, then the technology I want to use is AJAX. However, I'm using Typescript on the front end. Is the technology still the same? Or does that change since I'm using TS and not JS? TypeScript is a strongly typed programming language that builds on JavaScript. I just wanted to ask just to make sure.

Comment: @markymark_prod: Typescript gets transpiled to JavaScript during build/deploy.  The browser is using JavaScript.  If your goal is to use AJAX then you would still use AJAX to achieve that goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can send both newID and results by implementing this code in server side,

```
response.json({res:results, id:newId});
```

And also, you can easily catch the newID from the frontend by,

```js
async function getData(data){
        try {                    
            const { data } = await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/getData", data);
        const id = data.id;
        } catch (error) {
            return ({error});
        }
    }
```

In the code snippet, "http://localhost:8000/getData" is the relevant address on the server side to call your function from the frontend, and because you are using the post method, you can pass any data inside of the "data" variable.

I hope this will help you

Comment: "axios" isn't being recognized. I'm getting errors when trying to use that syntax

Comment: Also, I see that you declared a const named "id", but then it's never used within the getData().

Comment: try to install axios by executing `npm i axios` command in the terminal. ' id' is just a variable name. You can use any name for it. But it contains the value of `newId`

Comment: I get the server-side code. I'm still having trouble following how to access that data via the front end using Typescript. I see within the function you're creating a constant called data and setting that to the post request through Axios. Where are you getting that HTTP request from? And do I just call this function within my form builder group so it populates the ID automatically every time someone creates a new record? from the front end.